# conda activate doesnt work for git bash How to Fix?

Tags: git-bash

```
$ conda activate number

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - cmd.exe
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

conda neden çalışmıyor bi modül kurmaya çalışlıyorum ama olmadı  conda yı yeni kurdum ve çalıştırıdm ama activate anahatrını kulanamıyorum

Comment: This isn't a git issue? Also, please write the question in English?